# Vue 3 slot maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a Dropdown component, that looks something like this:

```
<template>
  <Header/>
  <MenuItems>
   <slot name="items">
  </MenuItems>
<template>
```

I import this component into another component and then something strange happens:

If I write something like

```
...
<template #items>
  <MenuItem> menu item code... </MenuItem>
</template>
```

Everything is good, but if I have multiple items (which are components as well), somehow I get the infinite loop error. What's the problem and how to deal with that?

Comment: please share the code of `MenuItems` code

Comment: if you are passing childs to slot you should end the slot tag with </slot>, i think this could solve it !